# C if statements skipped over

Tags: c, if-statement, random

I'm currently learning C and am attempting to do the reverse of what some courses are asking for.  miniMasterMind is an assignment I found where the user guesses numbers randomly generated by the computer.  I'm attempting to make a simple flip on it, where the user tells the computer whether or not its guesses are correct for a user generated 3 digit number.

I have what I think is a fully working program, except my 3 if statements asking for user input sometimes do not work.  I can't see any reason for it, but after compiling I often find one or two of the if statements to just skip over the user input.  I put in system("pause")'s after each step to make it easier to see.

Each turn in the game, a different set of if statements seems to break.  Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    // Initialize variables
    int UCMain = 0;
    int CG1 = -1, CG2 = -1, CG3 = -1;
    int win1 = -2, win2 = -3, win3 = -4;
    char check1 = 'A', check2 = 'B', check3 = 'C';
    int turnCount = 0;


    // Print out start screen
    printf("Welcome to masterMind reversed!  Let's see how this works out!\n\n");

    // Accept user input
    printf("Type in a three digit number for the computer to guess.\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &UCMain, 3);

    const int UC1 = (UCMain / 100) % 10;
    const int UC2 = (UCMain / 10) % 10;
    const int UC3 = UCMain % 10;

    printf("\nTest print, UC1: %d UC2: %d UC3: %d\n", UC1, UC2, UC3);
    system("Pause");

    // Start game loop
    while (turnCount < 10)
    {

        // Random number gen
        srand((int)time(0));

        // 1st number
        if (win1 == UC1)
        {
            CG1 = win1;
        }
        else if (win1 != UC1)
        {
            CG1 = rand() % 10;
        }

        // 2nd number
        if (win2 == UC2)
        {
            CG2 = win2;
        }
        else if (win2 != UC2)
        {
            CG2 = rand() % 10;
            if (CG2 == CG1)
            {
                CG2 = rand() % 10;
            } // End unique check
        }

        //3rd number
        if (win3 == UC3)
        {
            CG3 = win3;
        }
        else if (win3 != UC3)
        {
            CG3 = rand() % 10;
            if (CG3 == CG2 || CG3 == CG1)
            {
                CG3 = rand() % 10;
            } // End unique check
        }
        // End random number generation

        printf("The computer guesses: %d%d%d\n", CG1, CG2, CG3);
        system("Pause");

        // Check if numbers are correct
        if (win1 != UC1)
        {
            printf("Is the first number correct? Y/N\n");
            scanf_s("%c", &check1, 1);
            if (check1 == 'Y')
            {
                win1 = UC1;
            } // 
        }// End 1st check

        system("pause");

        if (win2 != UC2)
        {
            printf("Is the second number correct? Y/N\n");
            scanf_s("%c", &check2, 1);
            if (check2 == 'Y')
            {
                win2 = UC2;
            } // 
        }// End second check

        system("pause");

        if (win3 != UC3)
        {
            printf("Is the third number correct? Y/N\n");
            scanf_s("%c", &check3, 1);
            if (check3 == 'Y')
            {
                win3 = UC3;
            } // 
        }// End third check

        system("pause");

        // Check if game is over
        if (win1 == UC1 && win2 == UC2 && win3 == UC3)
        {
            printf("The computer wins!");
        }

        turnCount++;

    } // End while

    // Win/lose state
    if (turnCount == 10)
    {
        printf("The computer loses!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should read about procedural programming and refactoring =) When whole code is one huge logic block, it is harder to understand it and identify specific spots and grasp the work-flow. Btw, maybe you don't consume whole user input, or consume too much. This is more than 50% of cases with similar symptoms.

Comment: You should call `srand` exactly once, at the beginning of your program. And don't cast the argument to `int`; it takes an `unsigned int` argument, and the cast could mess things up. It will be converted implicitly anyway. Change it to `srand(time(NULL))` and put it outside the loop (`0` is valid, but `NULL` is IMHO clearer).

Comment: Also break after the computer wins. Otherwise, the computer could win say on turn 5, print that it wins, loop another 5 times, printing that it has won. Then once it gets to count 10, it will print that it loses. Also if `winx == UCx`, then there is no point in reassigning it. It would be better to just skip the `if (winx == UCx)` and go straight to `if (winx != UCx)`.

Comment: Also in the hypothetical case that you did need to do stuff when both `x == a` and `x != a`, you don't need an `else if` on the second one, just an `else`, as `x` is either one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

it is not really skipped:
it is taking a character the newline character: '\n'

Using a scanf with a space before it:

```
  scanf(" %c", &b); // this one will work instead
```

Will tell the scanf that any white space characters (including the newline '\n') left on stdin should be ignored.

please read more about scanf [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` is reading **all** user input, including line feed and carriage return characters. If the user types "1" and presses enter, you'll actually get 2 (or 3, depending on the platform) input characters, one for the digit and one or two for the newline character(s). This will stimulate 2 or 3 iterations of your loop when you only intended one.